# Form.reset() without firing onChange

Tags: forms, dojo, reset

I know you can prevent the firing of onChange when setting the value of a dijit elements (ie. `textbox.set('value',value,false)`).  Is there a way to do this when resetting dijit.form.Form (`form.reset()`)?

My problem stems from trying to keep track of a form that is dirty (ie. textbox value has changed).  I capture the onChange events for the controls in the form.  The problem is that the form.reset() sends onChange events for each control that got reset back to the control initial state.  So a `form.reset()` will set my dirty flag since each control reset fires onChange.

I have seen possible solutions that involve resetting forms control by control, setting `_lastValueReported` value, then setting the value of the control, but it seems there should be a simplier solution.

If there was a `isDirty()` method on the form, that would be perfect.

or is there a better way to track when a form is dirty?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to prevent the onChange event being triggered when calling the `reset()` function as of now, looking at [the code](https://github.com/dojo/dijit/blob/master/form/_FormMixin.js#L64), what happens when you use `dijit/form/Form::reset()` is that it will call the `reset()` function of every descendant widget of that form:

```js
reset: function(){
    array.forEach(this._getDescendantFormWidgets(), function(widget){
        if(widget.reset){
            widget.reset();
        }
    });
},
```

The reset function (of at least all form widgets inheriting from `_dijit/form/_FormValueMixin`) is [implemented](https://github.com/dojo/dijit/blob/master/form/_FormValueMixin.js#L67) like this:

```js
reset: function(){
    this._hasBeenBlurred = false;
    this._setValueAttr(this._resetValue, true);
}
```

So as you can see, it simply calls the `_setValueAttr()` with the second argument defined (which triggers the change event).

---

So, the only way of changing this kind of behavior is by implementing it by yourself by overriding the necessary methods. For example:

```js
var MyForm = declare("my/Form", [ Form ], {
    reset: function(priorityChange) {
        array.forEach(this._getDescendantFormWidgets(), function(widget){
            if(widget.reset) {
                widget.reset(priorityChange);
            }
        });
    }
});

var myTextBox = declare("my/TextBox", [ TextBox ], {
    reset: function(priorityChange) {
        this._hasBeenBlurred = false;
        this._setValueAttr(this._resetValue, priorityChange);
    }
});
```

This allows you to add a parameter called `priorityChange` to the `reset()` function, which allows you to trigger the event (or not).

A full example can be found on JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/f954z/

---

If you don't want to reimplement the `reset()` function of all form widgets (I only did `dijit/form/Form` and `dijit/form/TextBox`), then the best you can do is open a ticket and hope that it gets implemented.

Comment: Thanks, it's been so long I had to go back and see what I ended up doing.  I actually created a reset for each form in my app, and it essentially does the reset on each element in the form with a .set and then a ._lastValueReported.